# Angularjs app on Heroku: HTTPS request gets cancelled and replaced by an HTTP request, which gets blocked due to mixed content

Tags: node.js, angularjs, heroku

I have hosted an angularjs app on Heroku. It uses SWAPI api to fetch json data. The strange thing that's happening is the login call succeeds, alloing user to log into the app, but the request from home route fails due to the reason mentioned in the title. The app works fine on local.

Heroku app: https://starwarsapprishabh.herokuapp.com

Login:

Name : Luke Skywalker

Birth Year: 19BBY

Github repo: https://github.com/rishab-git/starwarsapp

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
The error was due to a missing slash before '?' in the request URL.